# How do I change the jQuery UI content background to white?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I tried modifying jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css but there's still an off white (almost grey) bar at the top.  Can anyone please help?

Comment: You should just post your CSS and maybe a screenshot to help here, it sounds like a pretty specific quirk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to search the whole CSS for instances of `ui-widget-content` and delete de background-* tags from them.

Or use the CSS editor namuol pointed, choose cupertino > edit > go to header or content and click the square with a gradient and select the flat square.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off editing a theme using the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and previewing the changes as you go than hacking the CSS and hoping for the best.

Comment: How do I do this with an existing theme?

Comment: If it's one of the standard gallery themes, you can just select it in the "Gallery" tab and modify things, then click "Download Theme". If it's a non-standard theme, I'm not really sure whether it's possible or not.

Comment: I did it.  I reloaded a new custom theme and it fixed everything.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try setting  `.ui-widget-header` class to `background-color:#ffffff`

P.S.: you can also turn off bg image (`background-image:none`) for that class...

Comment: Thanks, but it's still the same, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this css:

```
.ui-widget-header {
    background-color:#ffffff !important;
    background-image:none !important;
    border:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

apply data-theme="a" or whatever theme you want to the div and it will apply the required theme